# Bot to sift through every page of a website

Tags: mysql, wpf, vb.net, winforms, bots

I'd like to make a bot that can sift through every page on a website, for instance walmart.com.

This isn't a spam bot, and it's not going to be used for any malice reasons, it's purely a data mining exercise I'd like to do to sharpen my skills. I essentially want to grab every sku from walmart.com, and log the price in a database. I can manage finding the skus and getting the prices for each sku, as well as saving it to MySQL, what I have no idea how to do is go to walmart.com, and then automatically open each product page using code. I understand this might be a pretty big task to accomplish, and I'm willing to put in the time and effort to make it happen if someone could just point me in the right direction. At this point I'm pretty clueless as to how to even begin opening every product page.

I'm programming with VB.Net, but I'm open to win forms, WPF, or console solutions. Would love to hear what people think about this.

Comment: I think that Walmart may see this as a suspected DOS attack and block your IP so we wary of that (especially if doing this on a company machine as your company IP may get blacklisted)

Comment: You raise a good point. I'm going to run this project on a "throw away" machine at home that I got free from work :) so if I get blocked, well, I guess I'll just have to stop shopping at walmart (not a big loss in my book, I don't shop at walmart) :) If I can bring this project to fruition, I'll post here whether I get blocked or not for anyone interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a utility like HTML agility pack. This is the best way for someone to parse and mine data in .net that I know of. You can download it here http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

here is some code that will extract all the links within a html page

```
 Private Sub LoadLinks(ByVal page As String)
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument

    doc.Load(pathFront & page)

    mainsource.Title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title").InnerText

    For Each link As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")

        Dim att As HtmlAttribute = link.Attributes("href")

        If att.Value.Contains(".htm") Then

            mainsource.LinkList.Add(New PageLinks With {.PageLink = att.Value})


        End If

    Next

    For Each sublink In mainsource.LinkList

        Dim innerDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument

        innerDoc.Load(pathFront & sublink.PageLink)

        Dim subsource As QadLinkHeader = New QadLinkHeader

        subsource.Title = innerDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title").InnerText
        If Not innerDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]") Is Nothing Then

            For Each innerlink As HtmlNode In innerDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")

                Dim att As HtmlAttribute = innerlink.Attributes("href")

                subsource.LinkList.Add(New PageLinks With {.PageLink = att.Value})

            Next

        End If

        mainsource.NestedPageLinks.Add(subsource)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely be looking into this. Off the top of your head, do you know, can I use this utility without specifying the hrefs I want to look at? My ultimate vision here is to go to walmart.com, and then just loop through every product page they have without specifying any links. Do you know if I can utilize the agility pack in this way?

Comment: Absolutely you can use recursion and xpath to find any html element and get the contents..

Comment: I updated the answer with code

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This will get me started. At least YOU were intelligent enough to understand my question. Apparently the mods here aren't too great at comprehending the English language :)

Comment: No problem... I understand exactly where you coming from..